# PySide6 with Matplotlib don't work on MacOs

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyside

I am trying to get a matplotlib plot showing in a pyside6 app but it doesn't run, I am using macOS ventura.

this is the code

```
import sys
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Create the maptlotlib FigureCanvas object,
        # which defines a single set of axes as self.axes.
        sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        sc.axes.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [10,1,20,3,40])
        self.setCentralWidget(sc)

        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

and the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/u/Downloads/Function-Plotter-main/app/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
  File "/Users/u/Downloads/Function-Plotter-main/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .backend_qtagg import (    # noqa: F401, E402 # pylint: disable=W0611
  File "/Users/u/Downloads/Function-Plotter-main/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qtagg.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .backend_qt import (
  File "/Users/u/Downloads/Function-Plotter-main/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py", line 76, in <module>
    for mod, key in [
  File "/Users/u/Downloads/Function-Plotter-main/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py", line 76, in <listcomp>
    for mod, key in [
AttributeError: type object 'PySide6.QtCore.Qt' has no attribute 'ControzlModifier'
```

i did try to use tkagg backend but of no use, Also did try to matplotlib.use('MACOS')

Answer (score 1):

the code can run prefectly on my mac, you can check the package version, my is

```
Installing collected packages: shiboken6, PySide6-Essentials, PySide6-Addons, PySide6
Successfully installed PySide6-6.5.1.1 PySide6-Addons-6.5.1.1 PySide6-Essentials-6.5.1.1 shiboken6-6.5.1.1
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: I checked them, I have all of them installed but still the same problem

Comment: what is the version of matplotlib,  My is "matplotlib              3.7.1
matplotlib-inline       0.1.6"

Comment: im using `python 3.7.10` 
i tried 
`pip index versions matplotlib
WARNING: pip index is currently an experimental command. It may be removed/changed in a future release without prior warning.
matplotlib (3.5.3)
Available versions: 3.5.3, 3.5.2, 3.5.1, 3.5.0, 3.4.3, 3.4.2, 3.4.1, 3.4.0, 3.3.4, 3.3.3, ...  INSTALLED: 3.5.3
  LATEST:    3.5.3
`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue and get Matplotlib working with PySide6 on macOS by following these steps:

1. I had `Python 3.7.10` installed.
2. I discovered that when updating `PySide6 to version 6.4.0 or higher`, it's also necessary to update `Matplotlib to version 3.6.2 or higher`.
3. To check the available versions of Matplotlib, you can use the command:

   ```
   `pip show matplotlib.`
   ```

If you see that the latest version listed is `3.5.3`, it may be due to the Python version you are using.
4. In my case, I had to downgrade PySide6 to version 6.3.2 by running the command:

```
`pip install pyside6==6.3.2.`
```

5. After downgrading PySide6, the Matplotlib integration with PySide6 worked perfectly fine.
   I hope this solution helps you get Matplotlib working with PySide6 on macOS.